# Excel-VBA Duplicate data transfer message

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which opens another spreadsheet, copies, and pastes the desired data from spreadsheet a to spreadsheet b.

The first cell of each column is a pasted date.

```
 'Copy and Pastes Values to Trend Sheet
 b.Sheets("SPRAY").Range("BW1:BW56").Copy
 a.Sheets("SPRAY").Range("IIV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecialxlValues
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Currently, duplicate data can be transferred.
How can I display a message box if the date already exists in spreadsheet b?

Comment: Use the `Match` function to test for existence of a value in a range.  Then use `MsgBox` function to display warning to user and `Exit Sub` to abort the procedure early. Revise your question when you get stuck, and include the code you're trying to use and specific problem statement.

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with more information about where the possible duplicate dates are in the both the existing data and the data you are copying.